# Compactness of a space of sequence of functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, arzela-ascoli

Given that

1) $E=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_k\}$ is a finite set.

2) $\bar a>0$ is some finite constant so that $[0,\bar a]$ is a compact set.

Show that the following space of sequence of functions is compact in some topology.

$\mathcal{F}=\big\{\{f_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}|f_t:E^{t+1}\rightarrow[0,\bar a]\big\}$

I have some background in analysis, but assume that I'm a complete noob about topology, which I kind of am, so I need clear steps of the proof. I was told I should probably use Arzela-Ascoli and/or Tychonoff's Theorem at some point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The different functions have different domains?

Comment: Yes they do, but each domain consists of finite number of points since the cartesian product $E^{t+1}$ is a finite set for each t.

Comment: If the domains are different, the question does not make much sense. And "some topology" includes the indiscrete topology?

Comment: What if $\mathcal{F}=\big\{\{f_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}|f_t:E^{\infty}\rightarrow[0,\bar a]\big\}$? Could you then be able to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact?

Comment: If your "space of sequence of functions" is ($[0,\bar a]^{E^\infty})^{\Bbb N}$, then is trivially compact in the product topology (Tychonoff). $E$ being finite is irrelevant.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112404/proving-that-set-of-bounded-stochastic-processes-is-compact ..... I see, that makes a lot of sense. Some time ago, I posted this question (click the link) on this board and nobody responded. Would it be accurate to say that what you said also answers my previous question? You will see that I am talking about random variables in the link, but $\mathcal{F}$ above is essentially a sequence of random variables defined on $E^{\infty}$. Measurability condition in my previous post implies we are talking about a closed subset of $\mathcal{F}$ (right?).